# Drawing graphs in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

**What do you call drawing graphs in topological spaces? Where can I learn more about it?**

I'm interested in collecting some general strategies for showing that two topological spaces are not homeomorphic.

I tried thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and how to distinguish them topologically and came up with the following, based on the intuitive idea that you can *draw a triangle on a piece of paper*, but not on a straight line.

Let a representation $R$ of a graph $G = (G_V, G_E)$ be a family of sets such that:

$$ \text{for all distinct $a$, $b$ among the vertices of $G$}, a \cap b \neq \varnothing \;\; \text{if and only if} \;\; (a, b) \in G_E  $$

Let's say that a set $X$ is a *line segment* if and only if it is the homeomorphic image of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology.

Let's say that a graph representation in a topological space is a *triangle* if and only if:

1. it has exactly three sets.
2. every set is a line segment.
3. every pair of distinct line segments meets at exactly one point.

I claim that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ has a triangle, but $\mathbb{R}$ does not.

The closest that you can get in $\mathbb{R}$ is the pseudotriangle:

$$ \{ [-1, 0], [0, 1], (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \} $$

However, the pseudotriangle fails to be a triangle because $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) $ is not compact and hence not a line segment.

My question is somewhat similar to [this one from two years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306307/embedding-of-graphs-in-topological-spaces), but it doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Your definition of "line segment" is broken: "bounded" has no meaning in a topological space (you need a metric), and more seriously the boundary of a line segment (as usually understood) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the whole thing, not just the endpoints. Why not just define "line segment" as "homeomorphic image of $[0,1]$"? (If you really want to avoid referring to the unit interval or similar, you can say "compact connected set with exactly two non-[cut points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_point).")

Comment: Also, your $\wedge$ should be $\cap$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any easy argument showing $\mathbb{R}^2 \not \cong \mathbb{R}$ is that removing a point disconnects $\mathbb{R}$ but doesn't disconnect $\mathbb{R}$. This could be related to the fact that there exists a loop $\gamma$ around 0 contained entirely in $\mathbb{R}^2 - 0$ but no such loop exists for $\mathbb{R}$ (since $\mathbb{R} - 0$ is not connected). So $\gamma$ plays the role of the triangle, and of course, is just the image of $S^1 \cong [0,1]/\sim$. So this "drawing graphs" could be seen as considering closed loops $\gamma \colon S^1 \to X$. This just brings us to the fundamental group, which you can read more about in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book and he also discusses graphs.

Another source is Munkres's Topology book which has a specific section in chapter 10 that discusses embedding graphs in the plane. Specifically, if $G$ has $n$ vertices, then there's an obvious realization of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the vertices are the basis vectors $e_i = (0,...,1,...,0)$ and the edges are the lines between $e_i,e_j$ if $(i,j) \in E$. You can see that no lines overlap. So per Munkres, drawing a graph in a top space is essentially just injectively mapping this same graph that exists in some $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The Massey Algebraic Topology book has a very detailed discussion of what graphs can be embedded on what surfaces.